# PHP Aligning multiple arrays of different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, visualization, data-visualization

I'm probably just overlooking the obvious but I'd like to blame it on the fact that I'm new to PHP.

I have some number of arrays being returned with similar information but differing amounts of it.

I'll put some example arrays below:

```
(t1-s1-1=1, t1-s1-2=1, t1-s2-1=1, t1-s2-2=1)

(t2-s1-1=1, t2-s2-1=2, t2-s2-2=1)

(t3-s1-1=1, t3-s2-1=1, t3-s3-1=1, t3-s3-2=3)
```

So I would like to make a table out of this information. Something like this:

```
test ..  s1-1 ..  s1-2 ..  s2-1 ..  s2-2 ..  s3-1 ..  s3-2
t1  ........1 .....1  ..........1 ....... 1.........1..........1
t2  ........1 .......X..........1..........1........1..........1
t3  ........1 .......X..........1..........X........1..........1
```

*( where x is something that wasn't there. )*

So every array has an `s1` but could have `s1-1`, `s1-2`, `s1-3` or simply `s1-1`. That creates very different sized arrays.

The problem is that each array can have wildly different information and because they are Indexed arrays instead of Associative arrays I'm not sure how to best equalize them. I can't consistently say index 3 is `s1-3` or something else.

I can't just loop through manually because I never know where a gap will appear. I can't look for specific indexes because the arrays aren't associative so the titles are built into the value and I don't know how to access them separately.

Any good ideas out there that maybe a newbie is overlooking? I'm open to non-tabular display ideas as well as long as I can easily sort and display the information.

Thanks

Comment: I've read your question many times and I don't understand what it is really.. Could you explain more and/or give an example using the PHP syntax with comments?

Comment: You should first convert it to a more useful data structure, like an associative array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your original arrays contain values as string, so for instance, in PHP syntax, they look like:

```
['t1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1', 't1-s2-2=1']
```

Basically, you should create a bi-dimensional array:

- go through all arrays and by using a regex extract the different parts, that is, for the first element in the array above: `t1` (the index for the first level in the bi-dimensional array), `s1-1` (the index for the second level in the bi-dimensional array) and the value `1`
- insert the value in the bi-dimensional array
- keep in a separate array, let's call it `allColumns` every second index above (`sx-y`), even you will have duplicate values you can, at the end, delete those duplicate and order it alphabetically

After that, you will have all the value in the bi-dimensional array but you still miss the gaps, so what you can do it iterate over the bi-dimensional array, and for every dimension `tz` (t1, t2,...), go through for all the values stored in `allColumns` and if you don't find the entry for that `sx-y` in the bi-dimensional array for that `tz`, add it with value `x` (or probably with value = 0)

I think an example can clarify the above:

```
// arrays of arrays, I don't know how you receive the data
$arrays = [
    ['t1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1', 't1-s2-2=1'],
    ['t2-s1-1=1', 't2-s2-1=2', 't2-s2-2=1'],
    ['t3-s1-1=1', 't3-s2-1=1', 't3-s3-1=1', 't3-s3-2=3']
];

// bi-dimensional array
$output = [];

// it will store all columns you find in the $arrays entry
$allColumns = [];

// iterate for every array you receive, i.e. ['t1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1', 't1-s2-2=1']
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    // iterate over every element in the array: 't1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1' and 't1-s2-2=1'
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        // extract the parts on every element: $matches is an array containing the different parts
        preg_match('/^(t\d+)-(s\d+-\d+)=(\d+)/', $item, $matches);
    /**
     * $matches[0] would contains the element if matched: 't1-s1-1=1'
     * $matches[1] would contains 't1' if matched
     * $matches[2] would contains 's1-1' if matched
     * $matches[2] would contains 1 (integer) if matched
     */
        if (!empty($matches)) {
            $output[$matches[1]][$matches[2]] = $matches[3];
            $allColumns[] = $matches[2];
        }
    }
}

// clean duplicates
$allColumns = array_unique($allColumns);

// sort values alphabetically
sort($allColumns);

// iterate over the just created bi-dimensional array
foreach ($output as $row => $columns) {
    // iterate for all columns collected before
    foreach ($allColumns as $column) {
        // if one of column in 'allColumns' doesn't exit in $output you added in the correct place adding a zero value
        if (!in_array($column, array_keys($columns))) {
            $output[$row][$column] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

To print the output you should only iterate over `$ouput`

This will be the array internally:

```
(
 [t1] => Array
    (
        [s1-1] => 1
        [s1-2] => 1
        [s2-1] => 1
        [s2-2] => 1
        [s3-1] => 0
        [s3-2] => 0
    )

[t2] => Array
    (
        [s1-1] => 1
        [s2-1] => 2
        [s2-2] => 1
        [s1-2] => 0
        [s3-1] => 0
        [s3-2] => 0
    )

[t3] => Array
    (
        [s1-1] => 1
        [s2-1] => 1
        [s3-1] => 1
        [s3-2] => 3
        [s1-2] => 0
        [s2-2] => 0
    )

)
```

It exists other ways to implement the above, like skip the step where you fill the gaps and do it on the fly, ...

**Updated**
The simplest way to display the results in a HTML page is by embedding a php script to iterate over the associative array and compose the HTML table (I encourage you to study and research MVC to separate logic from the view)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
// arrays of arrays, I don't know how you receive the data
$arrays = [
    ['t1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1', 't1-s2-2=1'],
    ['t2-s1-1=1', 't2-s2-1=2', 't2-s2-2=1'],
    ['t3-s1-1=1', 't3-s2-1=1', 't3-s3-1=1', 't3-s3-2=3']
];

// bi-dimensional array
$output = [];

// it will store all columns you find in the $arrays entry
$allColumns = [];

// iterate for every array you receive, i.e. ['t1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1', 't1-s2-2=1']
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    // iterate over every element in the array: 't1-s1-1=1', 't1-s1-2=1', 't1-s2-1=1' and 't1-s2-2=1'
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        // extract the parts on every element: $matches is an array containing the different parts
        preg_match('/^(t\d+)-(s\d+-\d+)=(\d+)/', $item, $matches);
        /**
         * $matches[0] would contains the element if matched: 't1-s1-1=1'
         * $matches[1] would contains 't1' if matched
         * $matches[2] would contains 's1-1' if matched
         * $matches[2] would contains 1 (integer) if matched
         */
        if (!empty($matches)) {
            $output[$matches[1]][$matches[2]] = $matches[3];
            $allColumns[] = $matches[2];
        }
    }
}

// clean duplicates
$allColumns = array_unique($allColumns);

// sort values alphabetically
sort($allColumns);

// iterate over the just created bi-dimensional array
foreach ($output as $row => $columns) {
    // iterate for all columns collected before
    foreach ($allColumns as $column) {
        // if one of column in 'allColumns' doesn't exit in $output you added in the correct place adding a zero value
        if (!in_array($column, array_keys($columns))) {
            $output[$row][$column] = 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
    <?php
        echo '<tr><th>Test</th>';
        foreach ($allColumns as $head) {
            echo sprintf('<th>%s</th>', $head);
        }
    echo '</tr>';
    ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($output as $key => $columns) {
            echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td>', $key);
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                echo sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $column);
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not positive I completely follow you but wouldn't this create a problem with actually displaying the data in a table or some other format where all the information is visible? My goal is to either get a table I can export to something like excel or perhaps embed into HTML.

Comment: well, that will be part of the View, but here, you have finally an array populated with all the needed values, and the gaps, as you wanted, with 0 (or 'x') values. The way how you will format this array depend on you, I mean, if you want to export to Excel, you can use a library like ``https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet`` or if you want to send to frontend you will use some render, even if you don't use it you can create a script which iterates over the array and insert the HTML tags properly. The output I used here was just ``print_r($output)`` to show you some kinda result

Comment: and I don't understand either what do you mean by `table`, AFAIK in PHP doesn't exist tables as native structures, you have arrays, objects,... but not tables

Comment: I just mean the natural language meaning of table. Not a PHP structure. If PHP had a table data structure I have a feeling that would solve my problem much easier. I want to be able to display the data in columns and rows where each array goes across the rows and each column represents a data category.

Comment: I updated my answer above to add some example of how you can display the data in an HTML table

Comment: I appreciate your advice and have found it helpful. You certainly put the most time into trying to help. I'm sure your code is probably "on the fly" for example purposes but just in case it comes up in the future your example table does not actually display information.

Comment: Do you meant that when you run the above example you don't see a table displayed? If that is the case, are you running under a web server like nginx or apache? I tested locally and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$final_array = array();
$temp_array = array();
foreach ($t1 as $t) {
  $isin = 0;
  $expression = substr($t, 0, strpos($t, "="));
  $expression = str_replace("t1-", "" , $expression)
  $value = substr($t, strpos($t, "=") + 1);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    foreach ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
      if ($expression == "s{$i}-{$x}") {
         $isin = 1;
         array_push($temp_array, $value);
      }      
    }
  }
  if ($isin == 0) { array_push($temp_array, "X"); }
}
array_push($final_array, $temp_array);
```

It's not a great solution because you're choosing to do this in a really odd way but you should see the gist of what how to get what you want from this example.

Comment: What's the alternative not really odd way to deal this situation? I wasn't aware I've made any decisions yet. So far I've just got data and a question about what to do with it.